# If $f$ is analytic on $(a, b)$ containing at point $x_{0}$ with $f^{(n)}(x_{0}) = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, analyticity

> If $f$ is analytic on $(a, b)$ containing at point $x_{0}$ with
>   $f^{(n)}(x_{0}) = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove $f(x) = 0$ for all
>   $x$.

Hi, I need help with the above problem. I'm working through a previous exam for practice for my final exam. Unfortuntately, I don't have any answer solutions, so I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem.

I do not know how to solve it. But, it makes sense to me intuitively because $f$ being analytic with its derivatives equal to $0$ at a point implies $0$ slope, and $0$ slope of the slope (and so on), meaning that $f$ cannot really move from there, which means it must be identically $0$. I don't know how to prove this, though. I don't know why it's necessary for $f$ to be analytic for this to be true either.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261148/if-f-is-analytic-is-this-true?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $f$ is analytic, is this true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261148/if-f-is-analytic-is-this-true)

Comment: Wait what? No that is not at all the same question ^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytic means you have a Taylor series. Write down the Taylor series.

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere. So, I can write $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^{k}$, right? Then if $f(x_{0}) = 0$, then we need $x_{0} = 0$, I think? I can't get anywhere further.

Comment: @joseph I didn't say MacLaurin series, I said Taylor. Write down the Taylor series at $x_0$.

Comment: $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_{0})f(x - x_{0})^{n}}{n!}$

Comment: @joseph now you're done

Comment: Because $f(x)$ equals that series at every point.

Comment: Yes. $\qquad \qquad$